# time complexity of the sample code

Tags: complexity-theory

I have been trying to compute the time complexity of my project. can someone guide me how to compute the complexity if the loop is like this.

```
while (k < K){

    for( int i=0; i<M; i++){

        // if condition
        // sets i = dp
    }

    for(int i=dp; i<M; i++){

        for(int j=0; j<=i; j++){

            // single stmt
        }

        // if else condition
        function call(); // assume this has complexity of N
    }
    k++;
}
```

And please provide some suggestions on how to identify the storage space complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Complexicity for this code will be   `K* (M+(M*((M*M)/2+(M/2)+N))`

```
  K-times for while loop
  M-times for first for loop
  M*((M*M)/2+(M/2)+N) - for nested for loop
```

your nested for loop produce half matrix example

```
  1
  11
  111
  1111
```

since full matrix complexicity is `M*M` then half matrix will be (`M*M)/2`
  + we take the whole diagonal we have to add `(M/2)`

Comment: Where's N? I think it should be K * (M + M*(M+N)).

Comment: sorry i typed wrong.. in inner for loop it was j <= i not M... now i have edited that. I have confused because of this i onlyy

Comment: But in that case, if we consider as M = 4, full matrix will take 16 times where as half has to be 8. but from your example its running 10 times right.. still something missing i feel or i din't get it correctly?

Comment: sure I got to add + M/2 since we take the whole diagonal

Comment: according to this half matrix example, it seems to be acceptable, but still i'm not expecting it that much on whole.. bcz my running time was very less when compared with another algorithm. Might be my explanation was not at best.  And thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity is calculated by the number of iterations the code will do. So when we dissect the code, there is a top level loop which will iterate for K times so the complexity to start with is K. Then there are multiple loops inside that loop, each nested loop complexity will be multiplied by the top level loop. So inside the top level loop, we have two for loops, one with complexity M, and another one with a nested loop inside it making the complexity for that loop as M*j. And N for the called function So adding all together the complexity of the entire code is **K* (M+(M*(j+N)))**

- K -> for the top level loop first
- M - > for first nested loop
- M * (j+N) ->  for the second nested loop, which contains a nested loop and a function call

Comment: sorry i typed wrong.. in inner for loop it was j <= i not M... now i have edited that. But there is a function call which we can assume as N complexity

Comment: But `j` is just a temporary counter, not an input size.

Comment: yah j loop runs until i times. But your explanation was nice and understandable for computing.

Answer (score 0):

Complexicity for this code will be K* (M+(M*(M+N)) and it is the maximum possiblity.

But still as per your code it also depends on what is dp set to i that can reduce the complexity.

then it can be

Complexity for this code will be **K*(M+(M*((M-dp) + N)).**

Comment: let set1 = {1, 2, 3, 0}.
In first for loop i will check for specific element and note its position. That position will be equal to dp. 
In nested for loop inside, loop runs from 1st position until i.